# How can the whole row not be displayed if there is an "x" in the row

Tags: php, html, angular

This is the table
[image: How to not display if the row have 'x']

### HTML

```
<tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let data of check" style="text-align: center;">

                                    <td> {{ data.send_date }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ data.trading_partner }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <i class="not" *ngIf="data.date == '3 days' || data.date == 'more than 3 days'">{{ data.date }}</i>
                                        <i class="ok" *ngIf="data.date == '2 days' || data.date == '1 day' || data.date == 'less than a day'">{{ data.date }}</i>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ data.purchase_order_number }}</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="data.warehouse_shipping_order == 1"></i>
                                         <i class="fa fa-close || not" *ngIf="data.warehouse_shipping_order == 0"></i> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="data.warehouse_shipping_advice == 1"></i>
                                         <i class="fa fa-close || not" *ngIf="data.warehouse_shipping_advice == 0"></i> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="data.shipping_notice == 1"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-close || not" *ngIf="data.shipping_notice == 0"></i> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="data.invoice == 1"></i>
                                       <i class="fa fa-close || not" *ngIf="data.invoice == 0"></i>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

### PHP

```
//PO CHECK FOR 940
            $get_940 =  "SELECT edi_850.purchase_order_number
                         FROM edi_850, edi_940
                         WHERE '$po' = edi_940.purchase_order_number";
             $result_940 = mysql_query($get_940);

            if($row_940 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_940)) {
                $row['warehouse_shipping_order'] = "1";
            }
            else {
                $row['warehouse_shipping_order'] = "0";
            }


            //PO CHECK FOR 945
            $get_945 =  "SELECT edi_850.purchase_order_number
                         FROM edi_850, edi_945
                         WHERE '$po' = edi_945.purchase_order_number";
             $result_945 = mysql_query($get_945);

            if($row_945 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_945)) {
                $row['warehouse_shipping_advice'] = "1";
            }
            else {
                $row['warehouse_shipping_advice'] = "0";
            }

            //PO CHECK FOR 856
            $get_856 =  "SELECT edi_850.purchase_order_number
                         FROM edi_850, edi_856
                         WHERE '$po' = edi_856.purchase_order_number  ";
             $result_856 = mysql_query($get_856);

            if($row_856 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_856)) {
                $row['shipping_notice'] = "1";
            }
            else {
                $row['shipping_notice'] = "0";
            }

            //PO CHECK FOR 810
            $get_810 =  "SELECT edi_850.purchase_order_number
                         FROM edi_850, edi_810
                         WHERE '$po' = edi_810.po_number";
             $result_810 = mysql_query($get_810);

            if($row_810 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_810)) {
                $row['invoice'] = "1";
            }
            else {
                $row['invoice'] = "0";
            }



            //Get all the result
            $data[] = $row;

        }
        function cmp($a, $b)
         {
           return strcmp($a["send_date"] , $b["send_date"]);
        }
            usort($data, "cmp");

        if(isset($data)) {

            return $res->withJson($data);
        } else {
            return $res->withJson(array('error' => 'Table is empty'));
        }

        mysql_close($conn);
    });
```

All I need is to not display in the row if there is an "x". Can someone help me I have no idea about this. The reason I dont want to display the entire row if there is and x because I want to separate it with another component.

All I need is to not display in the row if there is an "x". Can someone help me I have no idea about this. The reason I dont want to display the entire row if there is and x because I want to separate it with another component.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function in controller and use *ngIf to do the checking.

```
function checkX(data) {
    return data.warehouse_shipping_order == 0 || data.warehouse_shipping_advice == 0 || 
           data.shipping_notice == 0 || data.invoice == 0;
}
```

and outside of the tr, create two ng-container, one for ngFor, another one for checking.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of check">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!checkX(data)">
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
```

so the table row is not display if there is an "x". Note that
[more than one structural directive on the same element is not supported.](https://dev.to/wiaio/angular-structural-directives-like-ngif-and-ngfor-without-the-extra-elements-5c24)

Comment: What is controller?

Comment: In my PHP or TS?